# Show opening brace in CLion/JetBrains IDE

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

If I code a loop it looks like that

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Notice that I place the opening brace in a separate line (it is just the way I like it). The same holds for `if`-statements and other things.

If I scroll through my code to a point where I only see the closing brace and place the caret at it, PhpStorm shows a little pop-up with two lines of code: the line containing the opening brace and the line before that.

CLion only shows one line of code, witch contains in my case only the opening brace.

Is there a setting to change the number of lines that will be shown?

I have only found [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/highlighting-braces.html), but it only says that CLion shows the pop-up, but not how many lines or how I can change them.

Comment: I couldn't find the setting either. However, you can press `Ctrl+Shift+M` to jump between matching braces. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but I found that it's better than the _(somewhat useless, especially because I use a similar formatting as yours)_ single line that CLion shows... (btw, the setting is available since [CLion 1.2 EAP 142.5239.6](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/09/clion-1-2-eap-new-uild-142-5239-6-is-available/) )

Comment: @865719 Thank you. It is better than nothing. I hope someone knows how to fix this or JetBrains will add such a setting.

Comment: This has to be addressed from JetBrains' side as this implementation is language specific (PhpStorm devs implemented this moment differently as CLion team did)

Comment: I'd like this feature as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such setting or other way to fix this.

But now there is a [Feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4937#) in JetBrains' issue tracker.